# Generate Random String From Array

Tags: string, arduino, arrays

I have the follwing array:

```
  char song[] = {'c', 'd',' ', 'e', 'f',' ', 'g', 'a', 'b', 'C',' '};
```

I want to generate a random string of length specified by me like this `int len=10`

How can i do this

char notes[] = "RANDOM DATA GENERATED HERE";

EDIT: I am new

I have tried

```
char song[] = {'c', 'd',' ', 'e', 'f',' ', 'g', 'a', 'b', 'C',' '};
char fs[];
int lengthh=10;

int i;

for(i = 0;i < lengthh; i++){

 fs = fs + song[random (0, 10)];

}

String str(fs);


char notes[] = fs[];
```

Error

```
Circuit_11.ino: In function 'void loop()':
Circuit_11:109: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'char [0]'
Circuit_11:116: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here in this line:

```
fs = fs + song[random (0, 10)];
```

`fs` is a pointer to char and it can not be added to a `char[0]` type.
if you want to append to an array you must increment the index variable `i` each time.
just like this:

```
fs[i] = song[random (0, 10)];
```

In case you want to use appending just like that line code  you must use the String library of c++:

```
string str,song={'0','3',...};

str = str + song[random(0,10)];
```